# Deserialize dynamic fields with GSON into POJO

Tags: java, json, gson

I've tried so many ways, but without success to parse this Json to a Java Object using Gson library:

```
 "return":{  
      "48388":{  
         "status":"canceled",
         "operations":{  

         },
         "created":"138232386",
         "price":"12.50000",
         "volume":"50.00000000",
         "pair":"btc_brl",
         "type":"buy"
      },
      "51714":{  
         "status":"canceled",
         "operations":{  

         },
         "created":"1365465421706",
         "price":"1500.00000",
         "volume":"0.10000000",
         "pair":"btc_brl",
         "type":"buy"
      }, 
      "48754":{  
         "status":"canceled",
         "operations":{  

         },
         "created":"1383237058",
         "price":"600.00000",
         "volume":"0.50000000",
         "pair":"btc_brl",
         "type":"buy"
      }
      "success":1
}
```

There is a lot of topics about this, but none of them cover this type of json mapping.
I'm convinced that there is a simple way to do that, any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT:
I'm trying this:

```
public class Test {
    @SerializedName("return")
    public Return1 _return;
}

public class Return {
    public List<Map<String, Order>> order;
}
```

EDIT:

```
public class Order {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int idOrder;
    private String status;
    private String created;
    private String price;
    private String volume;
    private String pair;
    private String type;
    private List<Operations> operations;
    // All the gets and sets here..
}
```

Gson doesn't initialize my order object. The order object is always null. I can't find the correct way to implement this mapping.

Comment: Is this the literal JSON you're using? In that case, the problem is that it's not valid - you should wrap it in `{` and `}`. Otherwise, show us the code which you are using to parse.

Comment: As it stands, it's not clear what you're trying to do. I know you say "may to POJO," but what does the POJO look like? What have you tried? Where are you running into problems? We need more info if we're to help you.

Comment: The object Order contains the details, like status, operations and so on.

Comment: That actually looks like it should work. What is the definition of the `Order` class? What error are you getting? Please [edit] your question to include this information, do not reply with that information here in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

After a long battle I was able to solve using this solution:

```
public void deserialize() {

Gson gson = new Gson();

// For isr read InputStreamReader
Map<String, Object> map =  gson.fromJson(isr, Map.class);

System.out.println(map.get("success"));
Map<String, Object> map2 = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("return");

// Show the contents of return
System.out.println(map2);
```

}

After that I used an Entry object to iterate and set the values of Order.

Thanks!